# How to pass parameter in linux command at the end of the line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, grep

I would like to pass a parameter at the end of the line while I am giving a command in terminal.

So I would like something like the example below

`find /path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -irl "SEARCH_PATTERN" {} \;`

something like this format:

`find /path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -irl "$1" {} \; < "SEARCH_PATTERN"`

and by this way I don't have to go everytime and change the command in the  `-irl "SEARCH_PATTERN"` part.
Instead I will just give it more easily at the end of the line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a function:

```
mygrep() { find /path -type f -exec grep -irl "$1" {} +; }

mygrep waldo
```

Actually, why do you even need `find`?

```
mygrep() { grep -irl "$1" /path; }
```

Comment: Find is unrelevant. It was just in my example. I would like to pass it without creating any new files, if possible. In a `diff <$(cat xyz1) <$(cat xyz2)` mindset, but at the end.

Comment: @limitCracker I cannot understand what do you really want to do. Please try to reformulate it. BTW with an `alias` you can substitute a whole command with options, e.g. `alias Ls='ls -sF '` and after you can call `Ls here there` instead to write `ls -sF here there`, but even `Ls -d here`  instead of `ls -sF -d here`. If you need to pass _"inside"_ the parameters you need a function as said here above. If only at the end it is enough an `alias`.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing i can think of right now, for this particular case is to create a SEARCH_PATTERN environment variable and chance it each time you want to use it.

Quick example;

```
$ SEARCH_PAT="abc"
$ find /path -type f -exec grep -irl "${SEARCH_PAT}" {} \;
$ SEARCH_PAT="xyz"
$ find /path -type f -exec grep -irl "${SEARCH_PAT}" {} \;
```

etc...

Comment: It's even more cumbersome to have to set `SEARCH_PAT` every time. I would like to press **Up** then **Ctrl+w** to delete last `SEARCH_PAT` and then **Shift+Insert** to enter a new `SEARCH_PAT` at the end of the line.